# Add custom tab and page to BuddyPress profile page

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am trying to make an extra tab in the User Profile menu in BuddyPress.
So far, i can see the tab in the menu, but when i click the tab, i am being directed to a another page where i can see the content on top of everything and a list with user Activity, instead of seeing seeing the content under the menu (like when you click Activity, Friends, Messages, ect.)
I hope that made sense... Here is my code:

```
 function my_setup_nav() {
    global $bp;

    bp_core_new_nav_item( array( 
          'name' => __( 'Tester', 'buddypress' ), 
          'slug' => 'tester', 
          'position' => 30,
          'screen_function' => 'test_template', 
    ) );
  }

  function test_template() {
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'test_template_two' );
    bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'members/single/plugins' ) );
  }

  function test_template_two() { 
    locate_template( array( 'buddypress/members/single/tester.php' ), true );
  }
```

So, i can see the tab with the text "Tester", but when i click i'm getting directed to another page (http://localhost/my-site/members/my-user/tester/) where the content from 'tester.php' is displayed above the user activity.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

This will help,

```
function profile_new_nav_item() {

    global $bp;

    bp_core_new_nav_item(
    array(
        'name'                => 'Extra Tab',
        'slug'                => 'extra_tab',
        'default_subnav_slug' => 'extra_sub_tab', // We add this submenu item below 
        'screen_function'     => 'view_manage_tab_main'
    )
    );
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'profile_new_nav_item', 10 );

function view_manage_tab_main() {
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'bp_template_content_main_function' );
    bp_core_load_template( 'template_content' );
}

function bp_template_content_main_function() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => true ) );
    }
}

function profile_new_subnav_item() {
    global $bp;

    bp_core_new_subnav_item( array(
        'name'            => 'Extra Sub Tab',
        'slug'            => 'extra_sub_tab',
        'parent_url'      => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->bp_nav[ 'extra_tab' ][ 'slug' ] . '/',
        'parent_slug'     => $bp->bp_nav[ 'extra_tab' ][ 'slug' ],
        'position'        => 10,
        'screen_function' => 'view_manage_sub_tab_main'
    ) );
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'profile_new_subnav_item', 10 );

function view_manage_sub_tab_main() {
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'bp_template_content_sub_function' );
    bp_core_load_template( 'template_content' );
}

function bp_template_content_sub_function() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        //Add shortcode to display content in sub tab
    } else {
        wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => true ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful.

Comment: `bp_nav` is deprecated. Use `bp_get_current_group_slug()` instead. For example: `'parent_slug' => bp_get_current_group_slug();`

Comment: Extra Sub Tab is just displaying like content and having not own url ? Any update ?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [BuddyPress Custom Profile Menu plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-custom-profile-menu/). It allows you to append regular WordPress menus to the BuddyPress user profile page.